# Elementary system of inequalities - set of solutions

Tags: inequality

$3x-1 \le 1 +4x$

$\frac {5}{6}x + \frac {2}{3} \ge 1 + \frac {1}{2}x $

$\frac {x-1}{6} \lt \frac{1}{4} $

(This actually needs to be a system with a large bracket)

$\Rightarrow $

$x \ge -2$

$x \ge 1$

$x \lt \frac {5}{2}$

I compared the above reduced inequalities which gave me as answer that the solutions are from [-2, $\frac{5}{2}$[. I think it is correct but I'm not sure. Can someone affirm this or debunk this please and what's the reason? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $x \geq 1$ trumps the $x \geq -2$ so your solution set is $[1, \frac{5}{2})$.

To find the solution set, you take the intersection of each solution set.

$x \geq -2$ has solution set $[-2, \infty)$

$x \geq 1$ has solution set $[1, \infty)$

$x < \frac{5}{2}$ has solution set $(-\infty, \frac{5}{2})$

The intersection of $[-2, \infty)$ and $[1, \infty)$ is $[1, \infty)$ because $-2 < 1$. Furthermore, the intersection of $[1, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, \frac{5}{2})$ is $[1, \frac{5}{2})$.

Comment: Why is that exactly? And doesn't the end bracket need to be "["?

Comment: That should be $\left[1, \frac 52\right)$, since $x\lt\frac 52$

Comment: @Anonymous My use of the "end bracket" is such that $)$ can be replaced by $[$  $\;$That would look like $$\left[1, \frac 52\right[$$

Comment: Oops. Forgot it was a strict less than. Also I put ")" because I am more familiar with ")", but I can change it to "[" if you prefer.

Comment: I also expanded my answer, a bit.

Comment: Thank you, afterwards I also have read  somewhere on the internet that one should take the intersection of the reduced inequalities.